# Is Apache Olingo OData 2.0 Java Library support actions?

Tags: java, jpa, olingo

I need to call one a database procedure in a CUD operation, rather than direct insert/update/delete to the table. So my question is if I mapped entities with JPA, Is it possible for me to call a separate function (action a bounded operation, not a function import a unbounded operation) from the URL via olingo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Olingo V2 library only supports OData V2 features, since actions of any kind are only available with OData V3 onwards this is not part of the Olingo V2.